# How to control webview in android to display proper google visualization maps?

Tags: android, webview, google-visualization

I am trying to display geo map using google's visualization in android's webview

My web view settings  are as follows -

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.setInitialScale(getScale());
    //webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

//   String containing js to draw map using google's [Visualization:Geochart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart)

```
 String js = "<html><head>" +
                    "<script type='"+"text/javascript"+"' src='"+"https://www.google.com/jsapi"+"'></script>"+
                    "<script type='"+"text/javascript"+"'>" +
                    "google.load('"+"visualization"+"', '"+"1"+"', {packages:['"+"geomap"+"']});" +
                    "google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);" +
                    " function drawRegionsMap() {" +
                    "  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([" + 
                    "['Country', '"+name+"']," + build +
                    "]);" +
                    "var options = {colors: ['"+startColor+"', '"+endColor+"']};" +
                    "var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));" +
                    "chart.draw(data, options);" +
                    "}" +
                    "</script>" +
                    "</head>" +
                    "<body bgcolor='#E6E6FA'>" +
                    "<div id='"+"regions_div"+"' style='"+"width:100%; height: 100%;"+"'></div>" +
                    "</body>" +
                    "</html>";
```

The code is working fine . I get different regions of map with different colors. But I need that only web view  get translated in landscape mode by keeping default screen orientation of fragment (activity) as **POTRAIT** . Also when I click on region a popup displays the proper name of country, but popup also opens outside the region on click on any where in the map. Even I tried on chrome browser in mobile it has same problem. Where as the same visualization is working fine on normal web browser on computer.

Comment: already answered here. (WORKING)
http://stackoverflow.com/a/33117135/4647628